Filtering XML on conditions
I have the following XML which I need to complete further filtering based on certain conditions. Essentially when a row has another matching row (same attributes besides Status) I need to remove these rows from my output - a Row with a Status of "New" that has a matching "Removed" row I need to remove both of these as they effectively cancel each other out. I have working logic for this but my issue is when theres multiple rows which the same data, in my example below row 1 and row 2 cancel each other out, but row 3 has no matching "Removed" row therefore it should be out. My current XSL uses a Key to find the matches but with this approach I end up removing all the rows because a match has been made. Can anyone provide any pointers on how I could approach this?
<root>
<row>
    <ID>11111</ID>
    <Start>01052024</Start>
    <End>31102024</End>
    <Type>BB</Type>
    <Status>New</Status>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>11111</ID>
    <Start>01052024</Start>
    <End>31102024</End>
    <Type>BB</Type>
    <Status>Removed</Status>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>11111</ID>
    <Start>01052024</Start>
    <End>31102024</End>
    <Type>BB</Type>
    <Status>New</Status>
</row>

<xsl:for-each select="row">
<xsl:variable name="concatKey" select="concat(ID, '', Start, '', End, '', Type)"/>
<xsl:if test="Status = 'Removed'">
    <xsl:variable name="rowMatch" select="key('groupedRows', $concatKey) [Status = 'New']"/>
    <xsl:if test="not($rowMatch)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="Status = 'New'">
    <xsl:variable name="rowMatch" select="key('groupedRows', $concatkey) [Status = 'Removed']"/>
    <xsl:if test="not($rowMatch)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>

Use xsl:for-each-group to process groups of rows that form a group (same properties except status). Then within each group copy the first row to the output if there are more New rows than Removed rows:
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" 
   group-by="string-join((ID, Start, End, Type), '|')">
  <xsl:if test="count(current-group()[Status='New']) gt 
                count(current-group()[Status='Removed'])">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>


Hi, very delayed response to this, sorry. This isn't achieving what I'm after as I believe this would output the entire group. In my XML example the 3 rows would be grouped together and output but as row 1/2 cancel each other I don't want these output and only want row 3 (altho it does have a match)

Well you could change it to only output the last row using `select="current-group()[last()]" which works on the example shown, but I don't know to what extent that example fully describes what other input you might have to deal with. (One example does not make a specification...)
